# Oracle and JDBC calculate number of executions occur during a transaction and performance thereof

Tags: java, sql, performance, oracle, jdbc

I have the following code:

```
void updateRecords(long[] ids, Timestamp[] dates, Connection connection
{
   PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                             "Update Foo set date = ? where id = ?");
   for(int i =0; i < ids.length;i++)
   {
        statement.setTimestamp(1,dates[i]);
        statement.setLong(2,ids[i]);  
        statement.addBatch();  
        if(i %25000 == 0)
        {
            statement.executeBatch();
            statement.clearBatch();  
        }
   }
   statement.executeBatch();
}
```

The performance of this is dreadful, 1 million updates takes over 2 hours.  So in my multi-part question:

1) How many statements get executed on Oracle?
2) How can I improve the number of statements that get executed on Oracle to reduce the amount of time it takes to do 1 million updates?

This is Oracle 10g and Java 6.

I imagine this executes N statements where N is the length of `ids`

Comment: What's the source of your IDs and dates? If you could easily get them into a single table in Oracle, your bulk update could be reduced to a single update statement.

Comment: @GriffeyDog the source of those IDS and dates is from a third party source.

Comment: Well, if it's a flat file, ideally you could use [Oracle Datapump](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php) to get that data into a single table like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, oracle will execute as many statements as there are ids.

2) For something like this, your best bet would be to send the date in a single call to the database, and then do the updates with a stored procedure. For example, you could send the ids and Timestamps as an array, and then recreate your logic in a stored procedure.  Also, depending on your database structure and config, running commits every so often inside the stored procedure could help performance (assuming your operation doesn't have to atomic).

You can see an example [here](http://www.anilsaha.com/2009/05/passing-oraclesqlarray-to-stored.html).  Just change the types to match your requirements, and instead of doing an insert, do the update inside the store procedure:

```
forall i in 1.. example.count 
  update Foo set date =  treat(example(i) as T_TYPE).DATE where id = treat(example(i) as T_TYPE).ID;
end;
```

Comment: So could you provide a code example?  This sounds like the FORALL that is used in inserts, but I was unable to have that correctly function with a "bulk" update

Answer (score 0):

1. you are right, through we are executing as batches, Oracle is going to execute N number of updates on the database.
2. Did you consider using Bulk Collect / update via create table via select + stored procedure ?

ex - `create table Foo2 as select c1, c2, c3, <<date>> from Foo;`
     now drop Foo and rename Foo2 as Foo table.

Please see the below link for more information.

http://ksadba.wordpress.com/2008/06/16/updating-millions-of-rows-merge-vs-bulk-collect/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using the standard JDBC batching does not reduce the number of round-trip, see
[Oracle JDBC Developer's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oraperf.htm#i1059053) :

> The Oracle implementation of standard update batching does not
>   implement true batching for generic statements and callable
>   statements. Even though Oracle JDBC supports the use of standard
>   batching for Statement and CallableStatement objects, you are unlikely
>   to see performance improvement.

Have you tried their own 'Oracle Update Batching' explained in the same document ?